# How to plot two unknowns in maple 14?

Tags: maple

This doesn't works in Maple 14. Why? How can I plot this function?
$$\text{plot}\left(\frac{x^2 \cdot y^2}{x^2+y^2},x,y = -\infty .. \infty\right);$$
Here's the original function (where is it continuous?):
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if } x^2+y^2 \neq 0, \\
0, & \text{if } x^2+y^2=0.
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following codes seperately:

> plot3d((x^2*y^2)/(x^2+y^2), x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10);

or

> with(plots);
>
> implicitplot3d(z = (x^2*y^2)/(x^2+y^2), x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10, z = 0 .. 50, numpoints = 20000);

In both cases, your plot is

[image]

Note that in 3D, Maple cannot handle the infinite ranges as you desired.

Comment: Wow...very cool! +1

Comment: nice one :) (I updated the Q with the original q from a book)

Comment: I just installed maple today :D but it looks like a good software :) I just need to know "where is it continuous?"

Answer (score 0):

Your function is $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}$. The function depends of two variables. So, if you want to draw the function, you will result with a 3-dimensional-plot.

The maple-function is called [plot3d](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plot3d).

Comment: Thanks, good to know.. now I only need to know where is it continuous?